# Confusion matrix from supervised learning

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, confusion-matrix

I am performing a supervised classification in GEE and want to verify how well my classifier has got trained.
For this, I found a method `confusionMatrix()` and my respective program is

```
var training = india_image.sampleRegions(ft,['class'],30);
var trained = ee.Classifier.cart().train(training, 'class', new_bands);

var trainAccuracy = trained.confusionMatrix();

var exportAccuracy = ee.Feature(null, {matrix: trainAccuracy.accuracy()});

// Export the FeatureCollection.
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ee.FeatureCollection(exportAccuracy),
  description: 'exportAccuracy',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

The exported csv is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I39jLEEB9I845DVeAQK2Y05k-2vKzepl)

Can you please explain it or give some suggestion about how to find presision, recall and accuracy